# Javascript variable equal to json data file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple javascript file, javascriptvar.js, which contains a json within that file like this:

```
  var ajavascriptjsonvariable = {   
            id: "someid",
            name: "somerandomname",
           data: {},
           children: []       
       };
```

What i am trying to do is to simply make the var ajavascriptjsonvariable equal to a text file where the json is stored. So i create a file called "data.json" with this inside:

```
      { 
              id: "someid",
              name: "somerandomname",
             data: {},
             children: []       
          }
```

(I'm not sure if i need a semicolon in the end of data.json or not?)

And now i try to make the variable  ajavascriptjsonvariable in the js file read the data.json file, but it won't go through. Here's what i do:

```
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){});
 var ajavascriptjsonvariable = data;
```

How do i get the ajavascriptjsonvariable = the data.json file?

Edit, sorry, quotes were a typo, corrected them, what i am asking is i think i'm supposed to include something into function(data){} brackets part to make ajavascriptjsonvariable read the data.json file, i don't know that part, that's what i'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

first of all the JSON wont validate it should look like this

```
{
    "id": "someid",
    "name": "somerandomname",
    "data": {},
    "children": []
}
```

next since you are making an ajax call here, u must assign the value inside the ajax callback function

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    var ajavascriptjsonvariable = data;
    /* Rest of the code with uses the "ajavascriptjsonvariable" variable */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, in 99% of all cases assigning a value to a variable which you do not use in the callback function is wrong. Here's what you *should* do:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    // use data here
});
```

Obviously you *can* assign `data` to some other variable that exists in an outer scope, but then you cannot just use it after the `$.getJSON()` call! You need to call whatever codes relies on the result from your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyVariableModule = (function($){

var myJavaScriptJsonVariable = null;

var getJsonFile = function(){
    return $.getJSON("data.json").done(function(data) {
     myJavaScriptJsonVariable = $.trim(data);
    });
};

return {
      makeComparison : makeComparison 
};  
})(jQuery);
```